# Update Jcrop image in a Rails site

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

**(Edit- I think this is a scope issue. I'm trying to access an instance of Jcrop from javascript which is loaded AFTER the initial page load and Jcrop has already been called.)**

So, I've found some great info on how to do this, but I think my problem is that I've got a combination of coffeescript to create an instance of Jcrop, and later I use a javascript template.

I'm pretty sure I'm not getting access to the my instance of Jcrop to update the image using setImage.

Here's the coffeescript file:

```
jQuery ->

  window.jcrop_api = new ProfilePicCropper()

class ProfilePicCropper
  constructor: ->
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop
      aspectRatio: 1
      setSelect: [0, 0, 600, 600]
      onSelect: @update
      onChange: @update


  update: (coords) =>
    $('#user_crop_x').val(coords.x)
    $('#user_crop_y').val(coords.y)
    $('#user_crop_w').val(coords.w)
    $('#user_crop_h').val(coords.h)
    @updatePreview(coords)

  updatePreview: (coords) =>
          $('#preview').css
                  width: Math.round(100/coords.w * $('#cropbox').width()) + 'px'
                  height: Math.round(100/coords.h * $('#cropbox').height()) + 'px'
                  marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.w * coords.x) + 'px'
                  marginTop: '-' + Math.round(100/coords.h * coords.y) + 'px'
```

And, later in a javascript template loaded into the same page, I want to update that image, but can't get it to work:

```
<% if @user.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload picture: <%= j @user.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>

  jcrop_api.setImage("<%= @user.profilepic.url(:large_pic) %>", function(j){
    jcrop_api.setOptions({ onChange: updatePreview,
    onSelect: updatePreview });
    bounds = jcrop_api.getBounds();
    boundx = bounds[0];
    boundy = bounds[1];
  });

<% end %>
```

So, I've tried a variety of global declarations in coffeescript as per StackOverflow recommendations, and a couple of variations of setImage, and still my image does not update. Any help out there?

Comment: I also tried... window.jcrop_api = new ProfilePicCropper() instead of the globalEval. It doesn't work, either.

Comment: Have you checked that your jQuery callback is being run?

Comment: @muistooshort ... I edited the post to show my preferred attempt using window.jcrop_api as the variable. I'm not sure a callback can help?

Comment: I was referring to the `->` in `jQuery ->` when I asked about the callback.

Comment: @muistooshort - Ok, I wasn't clear on that: the initial image loads fine and Jcrop works, but it's the update I can't get to work.

Comment: Don't you mean to say `jcrop_api.updatePreview` where you're currently saying just `updatePreview`?

Comment: @muistooshort - good catch, but I tried it both scenarios... with and without. No, success. I tried to alert jcrop_api.aspectRatio just to see if I was getting the right object, but it gives me an "undefined" which makes me think I'm not getting the instance of ProfilePicCropper.

Comment: Where does `jcrop_api.setOptions` come from? I don't see a `setOptions` in your `ProfilePicCropper`. Are you forgetting to forward that to `$('#cropbox').Jcrop`? Been awhile since I've used Jcrop so I'm fumbling around a bit myself.

Comment: @muistooshort - setOptions is a function in Jcrop... so, I should have access through my instanceof ProfilePicCropper.

Comment: But `window.jcrop_api` is an instance of your `ProfilePicCropper` class and that doesn't have a `setOptions` method. Your `ProfilePicCropper` probably needs a `setOptions` method which forwards to Jcrop.

Comment: @muistooshort - good point! What if I just set "window.jcrop_api = $('#cropbox').Jcrop" in the ProfilePicCropper class? Then, I would have a global variable for the instance of Jcrop (like, I meant to do earlier)? But, I can't get that to work, either. I've tried a million variations. Sheesh.

Comment: @muistooshort - not sure if you're interested, but I found the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved...

the problem originated in the coffeescript. I wasn't getting the appropriate handle to the Jcrop plugin. Two problems, basically.

The correct coffeescript syntax to get the Jcrop handle:

```
class ProfilePicCropper
  constructor: ->
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop
      aspectRatio: 1
      setSelect: [0, 0, 600, 600]
      onSelect: @update
      onChange: @update
      () -> window.jcrop_api = this
```

That last line is basically the solution to all my problems. The invocation requires a function call and that's what I wasn't doing properly.

Of course, there was the issue of scope in coffeescript encapsulating the variables, too. That issue is solved by attaching the handle to the window.